# 怒られるのが sentence construction

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, nominalization

怒られるのが怖くて嘘をつくのは、子供にありがちな行動です。 why did we use 怒られるのが as subject  ?? what is the sentence constructon

Answer (score 3):

> 【｛怒られる**の**｝が怖くて嘘をつく**の**】は、子供にありがちな行動です。
>
> 【Being afraid of｛being scolded} and (thus) telling a lie】 is a behavior that tends to be found in children.
>
> → Telling a lie for fear of being scolded is a behavior children tend to exhibit.

There are nested nominalized verbs, and the subject of the main clause is everything inside `【】`.

- **怒られるの**: being scolded (nominalized passive-form)
- **Nが怖い**: "N is scary", "to be afraid of N". It's in te-form (怖くて) because this is working as a reason/cause for the following verb (嘘をつく).

Comment: "perform a behaviour" sounds a bit weird. "...is a behaviour children tend to **exhibit**" would work nicely.

Comment: @user3856370 Corrected, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Great question. 怒られる is the passive form of　怒る. This means it has the meaning of 'to be told off'. のが is making it into a noun form, similar to the English 'being told off'.
Hopefully you can figure out the gist of the sentence from there; if not, I can help you with the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Is 'being told off' implicit or explicit? Are there any other ways to translate 怒られる? How is it different then, from 叱られる?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @BJCUAI, 怒られる can't be translated literally into English because "get mad" and "get angry" don't have passive equivalents – you can't say "children fear being gotten mad at." Naruto has gotten around this problem by using "being scolded" and Joshua Rowe by using "being told off." Both are pretty good functional equivalents of 怒られる in this context. In colloquial American English, a close approximation of 怒られる as it's used here would be "to get in trouble" (as in "children often lie because they're afraid they'll get in trouble [if they tell the truth]."